# Error occured during initialization of JVM

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface, libraries

I'm trying to start a Java virtual machine using JNI in C++ (I am using the Speech Recognition API [Voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/) ) During the initialization it says:

> Error occured during initialization of VM. Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries.

However my system has the JDK 1.7 and 1.8 installed and my path should be set properly.
I also tried to specify a new library path by passing 
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib";
as a JavaVMOption to the JavaVMInitArgs - with no effect.

DependencyWalker says the following DLLs are missing:

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

I have no clue what's wrong.
I am running my code on Win7 64 bit and the code is also compiled for 64 bit.
Furthermore my code runs properly on another machine.

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: On the machine it doesn't work did you install the runtime dll's corresponding to the MS C++ that were used to build the C++ code?

Comment: Yes, both machines uses VS 2013 to compile and run the code. Therefore the runtime dll's should be fine.

Comment: I have a similar problem when I build a JNI .DLL using MinGW-w64 on Windows7 x64.  I have all M$ Visual C++ Redistibutables from 2005 to 2013.  With EXACTLY the same list of missing DLLs in Dependency Walker